# ERROR [42000] The name WHSER is not allowed

Tags: sql, asp.net, ibm-midrange

I am getting a name error on my variable `@Whser` for my `ControlParameter` tag.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AS400fr %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AS400fr.ProviderName %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT PO180M1.POORNO AS PO_No, PO180M1.POSTAT AS PO_Status, PO180M2.PHSTAT AS LineStatus, PO180M1.POVNNO AS Vendor_No, PO180M1.POVNNM AS Vendor, PO180M1.POWHSE AS Whse, PO180M2.PHLNNO AS LineNo, PO180M2.PHPPN AS PartNo, PO180M2.PHVNPD AS PartDesc1, PO180M2.PHVNP2 AS PartDesc2, PO180M2.PHORTP, PO180M2.PHTYPE, PO180M1.POORDT AS OrderDate, PO180M2.PHLNEX AS DueDate, PO180M1.POCLDT, PO180M2.PHPUOQ AS OrderQty, PO180M2.PHPURQ AS RecdQty, PO180M2.PHUNCT AS UnitCost, PO180M2.PHSKUM AS StockingUOM, PO180M2.PHPUUM AS PurchgUOM, PO180M2.PHPUOQ - PO180M2.PHPURQ AS QtyRemng FROM PO180M1, PO180M2 WHERE PO180M1.POORNO = PO180M2.PHORNO AND (PO180M2.PHPUOQ - PO180M2.PHPURQ &gt; 0) AND (PO180M1.POSTAT = 'O') AND (PO180M1.POWHSE = @Whser) ORDER BY Vendor_No DESC, OrderDate">

  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Whser" ControlID="DropDown1" DbType="Object" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String"/>
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

What would cause that?